# SSIS Flat File Destination Export data issue

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

Am exporting data from a SQL procedure to flat file. My issue is 
i have a column called Test with data `1e2, 1e1, 1e3 .....` .When i export to flat file, data for this column looks like `1.00E+02,1.00E+01,1.00E+03...... .` 
What should i do to get exact data into flat file from SQL proc. Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: How are you getting the data, through an OLE DB Source that calls a stored procedure? And what is the column type of the source?

Comment: Yes am getting the data through an OLE DB Source that calls a stored proc. Column type is varchar(10)

Comment: Do you want the data like `1e2, 1e1, 1e3, etc.`? Or the actual values like `100, 10, 1000`?

Comment: i want data like 1e2, 1e1, 1e3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the column in your  `Flat File Connection Manager` has `DataType` of `string [DT_STR]`. This will avoid the implicit conversion done on your column by SSIS. See the image below:

[image: Setting flat file connection manager]

Comment: Column has data type of string [DT_STR] already. But the issue still exists.

Comment: @user28455 enable data viewer between the `OLE DB source` and `Flat File Destination`, are the values still `1e2, 1e3, etc.` or have they been converted before they reach the destination?

Comment: They are still 1e2,1e3, etc. They did not convert before they reach the destination.

Comment: @user28455 are you opening the flat file using Excel? I think the conversion is happening there. Try deleting the file and opening it with notepad instead.

Comment: Yes am opening file in csv. when i open file with notepad it is displaying 1e1,1e2... but user will open it with csv not notepad.

Comment: @user28455 so the data is correct and the SSIS package is outputting the correct results...so why's there a problem? The display layer is entirely controlled by Excel, and is independent of the "back-end" data layer. You can change the formatting of the values in Excel but wouldn't the users want a "100" which is displayed as "1.00E+2" rather than a string "1e2" which they can't do anything with?

Comment: Users need 1e2...data not "1.00E+2" because the value in that column is 1e2. The issue is when i export to Flat File from SSIS, i need excel/csv to display data as 1e2 not any other data.

Comment: You could add an apostrophe before the data item e.g. '1e2. This will stop Excel from converting the value.  However, you will still see the apostrophe in Excel!

Comment: One other option. Create a .xlsm workbook to run a macro on the Workbook Open event. This would open the .csv file via the "Data>From Text" data import. This macro could be recorded to convert the incoming data columns as text fields

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue,

Created a excel template with Test Column as text.

In SSIS, Created OLEDB Source, Data Conversion and Excel Destination tasks.
In Data Conversion i converted Test Column to Unicode String DT_WSTR.
I executed the package and it populated data into the template i created with 1e1,1e2...in Test column.