# Money data type is overflowed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, casting, etl, currency

I am working on SSIS 2008. My task is to get the stats from a table in OLE BD and save it in a flat file. I am using two fields in a table saved in OLE DB the fields are in NVARCHAR data type.  Amount and Currency are the two fields. I 
wanted the SUM of Amount, so tried using Decimal and Numeric to cast but it didnt work so used Money and it worked.

*My Query is:*

```
select sum(cast(PAID_AMOUNT as money)) as Amount, CUR as AmountCurrency, COUNT(*) as Records 
from Raw_table group by CUR order by 2
```

I am using a OLE DB source editor - SQl command option to query the statement. Clicking on the preview button displays the result without any error.

But when I execute the task i am getting an error:

> [Inv Stats [1]] Error: There was an error with output column "Amount" (17) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11). The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

so I captured the error causing row in a flat file by redirecting the error. and the file captured :

```
Amount,AmountCurrency,Records,ErrorCode,ErrorColumn
3073904391,JPY,9806,-1071607691,17
```

I am new to SSIS and have poor knowledge on data types. Please help.
Apologies if my description is not clear as this is my first post.

Comment: The datatype at the source is fine, what's the datatype at the destination (here the column is string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33633744/5605866) ? Try to use string at the destination, does that help?

Comment: If you go to `Advanced Editor > Input and Output Properties > Output Columns` on your source, what is the data type?

Comment: Thanks Gigga and Chris Mack, your suggestions helped. The datatype in both source and destination editor were Four Byte integer(DT_i4), first I changed only the destination datatype to string but got an error so changed the source datatype to string as well and it worked. Actually I had to use unicode string as I had imported the raw file using this datatype.

Comment: I have two more questions based on the solution: 1) The Amount field contains only Amount value but was NVARCHAR, so how did Money was able to cast and Decimal or Numeric weren't supporting the cast? 2)Now that I have changed the source and destination datatype to string using a cast that results integer datatype, will this not affect the conversion or how does this actually work i.e resulting datatype or cast in query is different from the datatype in editor. Hope I am clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value coming from your SQL query, of type `money`, with a value of `3073904391`, will overflow a column of type `[DT_I4]`. I'm not sure how you've ended up with `[DT_I4]` using that query in an `OLE DB Source` (when I set this up from scratch it defaults to `currency [DT_CY]`), but I recommend changing the data type in `Advanced Editor > Input and Output Properties > Output Columns` to `currency [DT_CY]`.

Comment: I recreated the source and now the datatype is [DT_CY]. I think because i was trying with different casting methods the datatype ended with [DT_I4]. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as correct if it's working.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql), if the `SUM()` function in sql server is applied on `Money` data type it returns a value of type `Money`

The related SSIS data type for `Money` is `DT_CY`, so you have to make sure that the Amount column data type is `DT_CY`, Just Right click on the OLEDB Source and go to the advanced editor to check this.

*OLE DB Source --> right click "Advanced Editor" --> Input/Output Properties --> OLE DB Source Output --> expand "Output Columns" --> Click on `Amount` column and change the data type from the properties to `DT_CY`*

If you want to learn more about SSIS data types and the related SQL server data type just follow the links below:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types
- http://bi-architects.blogspot.com/2011/12/ssis-datatypes-vs-sql-server-datatypes.html

Comment: Thanks Hadi, I will go through the link.

Comment: @Rammurthy is the problem solved? If yes you have to [accept one answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). Else give me a reply.